# another char shift C

Tags: c, string, char, shift

so i've looked through here and on google and tried various forms to try and accomplish this. it doesn't seem like it should be hard. i've tried getting a value from the char, tried just using math on it since i've read that a char in C is a number to the compiler anyway. what i have is an array of 4 strings. each element is another array of 20 + 1 characters (to include the null \0) what i'm trying to do is shift the value of each character in each string by a predefined amount using a variable "decryption_shift". what i thought i was doing is using 2 for loops, one to do one string at a time, the other to change each character in the strings. i've tried using pointers, tmp variables. yes this is a homework assignment, problem is it's a higher level class and they aren't teaching us methods/functions/syntax, they want us to research and learn on our own how to do it. i've already spent 2 hours trying to figure out this one snippet and don't know where else to turn. any help is greatly appreciated.
~justin

```
void decrypt_chunks()
{
    for (m = 0; m < 0; m++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n < 20; n++)
        {
            // int *chunksp = &chunks[m][n];
            chunks[m][n] = chunks[m][n] - DECRYPTION_SHIFT;
            // *chunksp[m][n]=tmp;
            // chunks[m][n]=tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens with the code you posted? errors? wrong behaviour?

Comment: Have you defined `m` and `n` as global variables? If not, define them above the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for (m = 0; m < 0; m++)
```

The loop will never execute because the termination condition is met on initialization. Try

```
for (m = 0; m < 4; m++)
```

Comment: ya sorry. i'm an idiot sometimes lol. looking at too much code and need to take a step back

Answer (score 0):

1. I can't see where DECRYPTION_SHIFT or chunks is defined (and initialized), so make sure you're actually define it globally or in the decrpyt_chunks() function (note: usually you write variables lowercase and macros uppercase, and if DECRYPTION_SHIFT is a variable you should write it in lowercase letters)
2. `for (m = 0; m < 0; m++)` while never run, this statement in words would be something like: *set m to ziro (btw where did you defined m?) and do the following things as long as m is less than ziro (never the case, as you set it to ziro)*

As this seems like a **very** basic problem, make sure you actually understand what a programming language is and how it works and consider reading one or two books about c (or almost any other programming language, as this homework would be in most modern languages pretty much the same).

To really make this thing interresting, what you basically do is encrypting like **Caesar**, so to implement this, the code could look similar to this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void decrypt_chunks(int decryption_shift);

char chunks[4][21];

int main(int stdr, char *stdv[])
{
    strcpy(chunks[0],"Hello World! And Bye");

    printf("message string:   %s\n", chunks[0]);
    decrypt_chunks(1);
    printf("encrypted string: %s\n", chunks[0]);
    decrypt_chunks(-1);
    printf("decrypted sring:  %s\n", chunks[0]);
}

void decrypt_chunks(int decryption_shift)
{
    for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
        {
            chunks[m][n] = chunks[m][n] - decryption_shift;
        }
    }
}
```